# How do I enable Volume Shadow Copies on a mounted VHD on Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, volume-shadow-copy

How can I enable volume shadow copies for a mounted VHD volume on Windows 8?

The mounted volume does not appear in the list of volumes available to enable VSC on:

[image]

As you can see, VSC is enabled for drive C: and works fine. The VHD volume does not even appear in the list.

---

The plot thickens. I created a normal NTFS volume on a real hard drive and it doesn't appear in the list either. I tried restarting the VSC service and it made no difference. Is there something I need to do to enable VSC on newly created partitions?

Comment: I have never known this to be possible.  Have you done it before?

Comment: No, I have not. I can't see why it wouldn't be possible though, if it can be done for normal drives.